# WordPress Error: Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a plugin that creates a menu page on admin dashboard:

```
function dp_manage_admin_menu() {
    add_menu_page('Manage Data', 'Manage Data', 'manage_options', 'manage-data', 'dp_manage_data_page', '');

    add_submenu_page('manage-data', 'Add New', 'Add New', 'manage_options', __FILE__ . '/add-new', 'tm_add_new_page');
}

// Actions
add_action('admin_menu', 'dp_manage_admin_menu');
```

In that page `manage-data`, There is a button for deleting data from DB:

```
<a href="<?php echo admin_url() ?>admin.php?page=manage-data/manage-data.php?id=<?php echo (isset($result->id)) ? $result->id : ""; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete
</a>
```

So if I clicked the first button it goes to "http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=manage-data?id=1"

Then I check if the `id` is sent, Then delete that result:

```
if( isset($_GET['id']) ){
    //Do something.
}
```

But I get an error, When I click the delete button:

```
Sorry, you are not allowed to access this page.
```

I can visit "http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=manage-data", But if any parameters are sent I can't access it anymore.

Comment: its seems you dont have the rights to delete from database

Comment: I have the rights to do anything, There is another page where I add new data, When I redirect the delete to that page and send that parameter, It's deleted

Comment: The interesting part which would be helpful to answer such question, is the code handling your request (inside `if( isset($_GET['id']) ){ … }`). As it stands, this question may only be answered by guessing.

Comment: Thanks all, The problem was in the URL, I answer my question to show it

Comment: Or I should delete the question?

Answer (score 4):

The load balancer takes HTTPS traffic, then forwards it as HTTP on port 80 to the wordpress server.

I was running issues with a redirect loop after installing wordpress. The solution was to add this bit of code to wp-config.php:

make sure that lines must be on top of page. I found this issue. And may be it can help.

```
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if ($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] == 'https')
 $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem, That's what the URL looks like "http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=manage-data?qid=6".

While there are another parameter there `?page=manage-data`.

So I should use `&` to ad another parameter.

The URL should be "http://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=manage-data&qid=6"

Answer (score 0):

Also search wp-setting.php file for "define('DISALLOW_FILE_MODS',true);" and delete it. Non of the above solutions worked for me except this one!

Answer (score 0):

It was happened with me for changing Table Prefix from phpmyadmin.

Comment: If the db tables have the prefix DpA_

then in db table ‘DpA_usermeta’  column meta_key, both values  ( DpA_user_level,  DpA_capabilities ) should be of the same prefix & DpA_user_level must be of 10

Answer (score 0):

This resolved my situation.

Check your user has wp_capabilities set to 'a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}'. You can use this to update in MYSQL command line

```
update wp_usermeta
set meta_value = 'a:1:{s:13:\"administrator\";b:1;}'
where user_id = x AND meta_kety='wp_capabilities';
```

where x is your user_id.